# Specify PostgreSQL passphrase non-interactively

Tags: database, postgresql, postgresql-8.4

Is there a way to set the PostgreSQL server's private key passphrase in environment variable or pass it as parameter while starting the server using pg_ctl command without non-interactively?

`PGPASSWORD` is used to specify only server's password but not passphrase of Private key.

Comment: I think it can be used only to set server's password not passphase used by private key.

Comment: The common practice is to remove the passphrase from a key when there's no one to type it. See [Creating a Self-signed Certificate](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ssl-tcp.html)

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think you can (assuming you are talking about the passphrase on a server's private key so it can support SSL connections).

The whole point of a passphrase protected key is that the phrase isn't stored on the server with the key. Otherwise you don't gain any security from it.